# sbt-launch.jar failed - Could not load main class

Tags: jenkins, sbt, jenkins-pipeline, sbt-assembly

I have a jenkins build to check sbt,  which is failing with the below error:

```
[sbt-check] $ /var/hudson/tools/java1.8.0_51/bin/java /var/hudson/tools/sbt-0.13.12/bin/sbt-launch.jar -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -jar  clean assembly
Error: Could not find or load main class .var.hudson.tools.sbt-0.13.12.bin.sbt-launch.jar
Build step 'Build using sbt' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Build using sbt' marked build as failure
Successfully triggered JIRA to update builds of this job
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in  9 second
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

The sbt package is installed on the server. I downloaded package SBT-0.13.12.TGZ from http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html and created its RPM to install it on my server. Package is installed and I have configured the path of sbt-launch in manage-jenkins.

Comment: I occurred the same problem. Did your reslove it?